# align/spread file content in vertically split windows

Tags: scrolling, alignment

I have a single buffer open across multiple vertically split windows and all the windows have `scrollbind` set. However, before setting `scrollbind`, I had to scroll down in second window in order to make sure that text in second window starts where it ends in first window. In addition, I had to scroll down the text in third window in order to make sure that it starts where it ends in second window. When this was done I set the `scrollbind`. Is there an easier way? Scrolling in all the vertically split windows is tedious.

// **EDIT:** I added a screenshot. As seen below, I have same file(`1000_line_file.txt`) open in three windows and I have scrolled the second and third window in a way that first line in second window is `line nr 88`, last line in second window is `line nr 174` and first line in third windows is `line nr 175`. At this point I want to execute `:windo set scrollbind` to lock the scrolling. However, this scrolling process in vertically split windows is tedious.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to make a couple of splits synced with an increasing offset, the routine would be:

1. Split the window vertically <kbd>C-w</kbd> <kbd>v</kbd>
2. Move to the next window <kbd>C-w</kbd> <kbd>w</kbd>
3. Scroll down one screen <kbd>C-f</kbd> (add <kbd>C-e</kbd> as needed)
4. Repeat steps 1 - 3

Now as all splits are open and you are on the last one, you need to bind them:

5. `:set scrollbind`
6. Move to the previous window <kbd>C-w</kbd> <kbd>W</kbd>
7. `:set scrollbind`
8. Repeat steps 6 and 7

Record the macro once and that's it. You can use `:windo set scrollbind` instead, but this way it will work even if you have other windows open. Here how it looks like in a register:

`^Wv^Ww^F^E^E^Wv^Ww^F^E^E:set scrollbind^@^WW:set scrollbind^@^WW:set scrollbind^@`

[image]

Also worth mentioning. Commands replayed by macro are not registered in the history, so `:` <kbd>C-p</kbd>  <kbd>Return</kbd> or `@:` will execute the most recent command *before* the replay.

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in Dr. Chips [MPage](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4545) plugin, which does exactly this. From the documentation:

> MPage shows a file in multiple windows, with each sequential window
>   showing sequential lines of text, rather like a book.
>
> Usage:

```
:MPage [splits]
:[splits]MPage
```

Answer (score 0):

`:syncbind`

This will *Force all 'scrollbind' windows to have the same relative offset.*

Just be sure you aren't using scrollbar of non-focused windows as it only works with focused window (and, of course, keyboard scrolling works).

**Edit:** I posted the above before the question had extra details added. However `syncbind` could still help with automating the syncing of multiple windows, each one page ahead of the preceding...

Let's say you open 2 splits (for 3 total windows) then do some unrelated work. Now each window is on a different line. But as long as one window is on the line that you want to be relative to this would set you up:

1. `:windo set scrollbind`
2. `:syncbind` (each window is now synced to the same line)
3. `:windo set noscrollbind` (temporarily unbind)
4. In second window: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F</kbd>
5. In third window: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F</kbd>
6. `:windo set scrollbind`

Obviously you'd want to put this in a script (or a macro per Sergey's answer).